# Issue with rendering geometry node. Viewport preview and render itself are different

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes

From the left, I have the result in the viewport shading. From the right render result. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

**UPD**
I was assembling this node tree by the tutor. The problem was in this node near *is Viewport*. I wrote too large values earlier and now everything is working! Thanks to all for the help and quick reply:)

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Maybe varying subdivision levels for viewport and render, maybe some blur compositing, maybe some motion blur…

Comment: Please be so kind and show us your node tree as well. As the question currently stands, it is almost impossible to give a clear answer. But first check if you use the node [Is Viewport](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/scene/is_viewport.html) somewhere in your node tree. If not, then the problem is probably not with your *Geometry Nodes*.

Comment: Obviously my tip could help you! I'm happy about that! But since this is a Q&A platform: could you write your finding as an answer below so that you can mark it as an "Accepted Answer" and the question thus appears as solved? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks to @quellenform for guiding me to the place where was the problem. The problem was in this node near "is Viewport". I wrote too large values earlier and now everything is working!